# Find and replace ASCII character with a new line

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I am trying to find every occurrence of an ASCII character in a string and replace it with a new line. Here is what I have so far:

```
public string parseText(string inTxt)
{
    //String builder based on the string passed into the method
    StringBuilder n = new StringBuilder(inTxt);
    //Convert the ASCII character we're looking for to a string
    string replaceMe = char.ConvertFromUtf32(187);
    //Replace all occurences of string with a new line
    n.Replace(replaceMe, Environment.NewLine);
    //Convert our StringBuilder to a string and output it
    return n.ToString();
}
```

This does not add in a new line and the string all remains on one line. I’m not sure what the problem is here. I have tried this as well, but same result:

```
n.Replace(replaceMe, "\n");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: We're also "not sure what the problem is here."  Because you didn't tell us.

Comment: What problem? And what result is it the same as?

Comment: It's not doing what I said it's supposed to do...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`char.ConvertFromUtf32`, whilst correct, is not the simplest way to read a character based on its ASCII numeric value. (`ConvertFromUtf32` is mainly intended for Unicode code points that lie outside the BMP, which result in surrogate pairs. This is not something you'd encounter in English or most modern languages.) Rather, you should just cast it using `(char)`.

```
char c = (char)187;
string replaceMe = c.ToString();
```

You may, of course, define a string with the required character as a literal in your code: `"»"`.

Your `Replace` would then be simplified to:

```
n.Replace("»", "\n");
```

Finally, on a technical level, ASCII only covers characters whose value lies in the 0–127 range. Character 187 is not ASCII; however, it corresponds to `»` in ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252, *and* Unicode, which collectively are by far the most popular encodings in use today.

**Edit**: I just tested your original code, and found that it actually worked. Are you sure the result remains on one line? It might be an issue with the way the debugger renders strings in single-line view:

[image: No newlines?]

Note that the `\r\n` sequences actually *do* represent newlines, despite being displayed as literals. You can check this from the multi-line display (by clicking on the magnifying glass):

[image: Newlines!]

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Your code works great, however the text is not showing up on a new line, although this could be a limitation of the library I'm using (the text is being written to a PDF file with iTextSharp).

Comment: @AndrewDeForest: Yes, it’s definitely related to the way you’re using the string; the result of even your original method was correct. It is likely the case that iTextSharp has a specific way of introducing newlines – similar to the `<br>` node in HTML – and you therefore cannot assume it will recognize/honour the .NET newlines. If you open a question with a snippet of the code you’re using for generating your PDF, you’ll probably get some help on how to convert string newlines to iTextSharp’s structures.

Answer (score 0):

[`StringBuilder.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93tx8bdw.aspx) returns a new `StringBuilder` with the changes made. Strange, I know, but this should work:

```
StringBuilder replaced = n.Replace(replaceMe, Environment.NewLine);

return replaced.ToString();
```

Comment: @banging The replace method of StringBuilder returns a reference to the instance, not a new instance.

Comment: MyItchyChin: considering that _everything_ (apart from primitives) is a reference in c#, why is the distinction important? I was implying that it was a reference.